# Can we directly unit test HTML embedded JavaScript functions?

Tags: cypress

Suppose we have a webpage with embedded JavaScript as in `index.html` as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <title>Cypress - Testing the Tester</title>

  <script>/*<![CDATA[*/  
    function foo() {
      return "bar";
    }

    function outputMessage(message) {
      document.querySelector("output").innerHTML += message + "<br />";
    }

    window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(){
      outputMessage(foo());
    });

  /*]]>*/</script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Cypress - Testing the Tester</h1>
  <output></output>
</body>
</html>
```

On page show (e.g. load) this inserts the string "bar" inside `<output></output>`.

If `my_cypress_spec.js` is:

```js
describe('The Home Page Tests', () => {
  it('Test HTML embedded JavaScript function', () => {
    // Assumes, e.g. "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:5500" set in cypress.json
    cy.visit('index.html'); 
    expect(foo()).to.equal("bar");
  }); 
});
```

then in the Cypress test runner I get a "ReferenceError ... foo is not defined". That is, it appears Cypress doesn't recognize the `foo()` function.

Is there a way for Cypress to directly unit test the `foo()` function? That is, without relying on ES6/ES2015 export/imports (where the above is refactored to put `foo()` in its own JavaScript file where it is exported and `my_cypress_spec.js` imports this)?

Attempting [@Fody's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72137563/3001761) my `my_cypress_spec.js` becomes:

```js
describe('The Home Page Tests', () => {
  it('Test HTML embedded JavaScript function', () => {
    // Assumes, e.g. "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:5500" set in cypress.json
    cy.visit('index.html'); 
    cy.window().then(win => {
      expect(win.foo()).to.eq('bar');
    });
  }); 
});
```

and I get the error "TypeError ... win.foo is not a function".

Comment: @jonrsharpe. If, for example, the second test was `cy.contains('Lorem')` then that `contains()` would depend on the prior `visit()`. Some cypress tests are therefore dependent, right?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, that's helpful. Note, however, the best practice you link to affords (properly) for a kind of dependency. Namely, as one option, "Move repeated code in previous tests to `before` or `beforeEach` hooks". Then each individual `it()` test can (properly it is suggested) be independent of each other while being dependent on, for example, a `visit()` coded in one of the hooks. But I'll note this better practice in the main post above. In #897 I'm getting the same problem JimLynchCodes got at https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/897#issuecomment-375375252.

Comment: See Edit 02. I'm using the specified `index.html` and (the Edit 02) `my_cypress_spec.js`.

Comment: Note people can view the post history if they're interested in how it evolved. For me, that test _passes_.

Comment: On history: yes but generally that's less readable. However, I think your current edits to the main post are fine (making the code even more minimal). Thanks for mentioning your test passes. That, then, is very strange. I've tested this in firefox and chrome (they both fail). I'll have to keep looking for something quirky in my environment.

Comment: Thanks very much @jonrsharpe and @Fody! This question is now fully answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fody's answer works. So, in full `my_cypress_spec.js` can become something like:

```js
describe('The Home Page Tests', () => {
  it('Test HTML embedded JavaScript function', () => {
    // Assumes, e.g. "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:5500" set in cypress.json
    cy.visit('index.html'); 
    cy.window().then(win => {
      expect(win.foo()).to.eq('bar');
    });
  }); 
});
```

However, the reason I was getting a "TypeError ... win.foo is not a function" was because in my `index.html` on my machine (not as originally posted above) I had an opening `<script type="module">`. Changing that back to `<script>` made the test pass.

So for completeness I'll tag this as The Answer while noting the insights come from @Fody and @jonrsharpe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well this will apply if you are using a more complex app, e.g created with Angular or React. Those frameworks have specialized test harnesses for unit testing.

For the vanilla JS example you gave, it's quite easy since `foo()` gets attached to the window of the AUT.

```js
cy.window().then(win => {
  expect(win.foo()).to.eq('bar')
})
```

[image]

Comment: What's "AUT" stand for?

Comment: I now see "AUT" stands for "Application Under Test". As at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-runner#Hovering-on-Commands